# Difference between push notification and nsnotifcation centre in iOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have question about push notification and the Notification Center. I have built an app and now I want to support notification the the time hits 0 I'm doing like countdown app shows the release date for games and title. 
Should I use nsnotifcation center or push notification

Comment: If someone wants to give negative marking then he or she must explain the reasons in the comment so the beginers can improve the mistakes else he or she has no rights to do that

Comment: You dont need Push Notifications you can acheive that with UILocalNotification. For Push Notifications you need coordination with server but for UILocalNotification you can do it inside your application so better try to use UILocalNotification

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm using nstimer rather than pickerdate

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need Push Notifications you can acheive that with UILocalNotification. For Push Notifications you need coordination with server but for UILocalNotification you can do it inside your application so better try to use UILocalNotification

For simple UILocalNotification

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotificationalloc] init]; 
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Your alert message";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

For `UILocalNotification` with timers

```
// Get the current date
NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

// Schedule the notification
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
localNotification.alertBody = self.itemText.text;
localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

// Request to reload table view data
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];
```

you can study in detail in here http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you, but I don't use pickerdate I use the nstimer for making countdown

Comment: Thanks and are you able to acheive what u wants then

Comment: The code looks good, but I want to make the notification fires when the timers go to zero I'm thinking about it

Comment: You havent acheive that is that